# Calling a server side function using a Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, jquery-events

I need to invoke a server side function when an item is picked in an ASP drop-down box.
Can someone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Just add `AutoPostBack="True"` to the dropdown markup and add `OnChange="YourMethodHere"`.

Comment: This question is overly broad; you're essentially asking for a description of .NET web methods and AJAX.  Google around for those.  If you have specific questions related to implementing such a method and calling it, come back and ask, but with much more detail, including some code.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's so early 2000's.  I think we can do better than that. :-) Besides, he did say "using a [sic] javascript."

Comment: @tvanfosson if he can cope with full post back then why not? You don't have to buy brand new car every year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within ASP.NET use the drop down selected index change event.  Alternatively for a client side event you could use JQuery and then use the following JavaScript function to contact the Server:

```
function CallServer() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'webserviceURL',
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanx buddy, I actually forgot to mention the JS part, I needed to invoke server side function using JS without postbacking the form...

Answer (score 1):

set

> ddl.autopostback = true ;

and fire `selectedindexchange event`

Comment: ...but this doesn't use "a [sic] javascript"

Comment: @tvanfosson: Although that actually uses javascript in the backgroud, I give you that is not probably what he tried to ask.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi - yes, I'm assuming that he intended "using some javascript that I write"

Comment: if you don't want post back don't you think it will be more feasible to use update panel to achieve your target use as many as needed so you can speed up your web application and save data transportation amount and also use update panel for this ddl and for that portion of web page which data you wan't to update.

Answer (score 0):

Add a web service to your project, and have this perform the actions/return the data you need on the client.  Then use AJAX (or JQUERY AJAX) to call this service when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

**Aspx**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**CS**

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //call your function
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking this doesn't meet the requirement of using (non-framework) javascript.

Comment: is there any need to be bound with some language 
Visual Studio and other IDE handle all that stuff it self they'll invoke javascript with ajax if you put this ddl into Updatepanel you're not required to do so